# How to solve the exception NonUniqueObjectException issued by Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am making a web application with `Spring MVC and Hibernate`, in both pro novice technologies, but I have handled other web fraweworks in other languages before.

I have a problem in a process, in which user, worker and work users are involved. When trying to create a compliance record, the system throws the exception `NonUniqueObjectException`, so the transaction is not valid and does not persist in the database.

I have been reading about this exception, but I have no repeated objects or that are in the same session. I even try to change the state of the corresponding objects with the `evict()` function without success.

The partial code of the application is as follows:

**ContratoController.java**

```
@GetMapping("/{idTrabajador}/{idUsuario}/{idTrabajo}/new")
public String crearContratoGet(Model model){
    return "contract/registerContract";
}

@PostMapping("/{idTrabajador}/{idUsuario}/{idTrabajo}/new")
public String crearContratoPost(@PathVariable(value = "idTrabajador") int idTrabajador,
        @PathVariable(value = "idUsuario") int idUsuario,
        @PathVariable(value = "idTrabajo") int idTrabajo,
        @RequestParam("txtSalario") String salario,
        @RequestParam("txtFechaTrabajo") String fechaTrabajo,
        @RequestParam("txtDireccionTrabajo") String direccionTrabajo){

    Contrato contrato = new Contrato();
    contrato.setSalario(salario);
    Date date = Date.valueOf(fechaTrabajo);
    contrato.setFechaTrabajo(date);
    contrato.setDirecciontrabajo(direccionTrabajo);

    Trabajador trabajador = this.trabajadorService.find(idTrabajador);
    Usuario usuario = this.userService.find(idUsuario);
    Trabajo trabajo = this.trabajoService.find(idTrabajo);

    Collection<Contrato> contratoTrabajador = trabajador.getContratoCollection();
    Collection<Contrato> contratoUsuario = trabajador.getContratoCollection();
    Collection<Contrato> contratoTrabajo =  trabajo.getContratoCollection();

    if(contratoTrabajador == null){
        contratoTrabajador = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    if(contratoUsuario == null){
        contratoUsuario = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    if(contratoTrabajo == null){
        contratoTrabajo = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    contratoTrabajador.add(contrato);
    contratoUsuario.add(contrato);
    contratoTrabajo.add(contrato);

    trabajador.setContratoCollection(contratoTrabajador);
    usuario.setContratoCollection(contratoUsuario);
    trabajo.setContratoCollection(contratoTrabajo);

    contrato.setUsuario(usuario);
    contrato.setTrabajador(trabajador);
    contrato.setTrabajo(trabajo);

    this.contratoService.deleteSession(contrato);
    this.trabajadorService.deleteSession(trabajador);
    this.userService.deleteSession(usuario);

    this.contratoService.save(contrato);
    this.trabajadorService.update(trabajador);
    this.userService.update(usuario);

    int nuevoId = this.contratoService.getLastId();

    return "redirect:/contract/" + idTrabajador + "/" + idUsuario + "/" + idTrabajo + "/" + nuevoId;
}
```

**Save function (The service invokes the corresponding DAO class, it is there where the save function is located)**

```
@Repository
public class ContratoDaoImpl implements ContratoDao{

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
public void save(Contrato contrato) {

    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.save(contrato);
}
```

The complete error is as follows

```
16-Nov-2019 18:38:13.255 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-26] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke El Servlet.service() para el servlet [dispatcher] en el contexto con ruta [/trabajaya] lanzó la excepción [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [edu.co.ucatolica.trabajaya.model.Trabajo#1]] con causa raíz
 org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [edu.co.ucatolica.trabajaya.model.Trabajo#1]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.checkUniqueness(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:651)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:284)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:227)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:678)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:670)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$5.cascade(CascadingActions.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:490)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:415)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:428)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:266)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:709)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:701)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:696)
    at edu.co.ucatolica.trabajaya.dao.ContratoDaoImpl.save(ContratoDaoImpl.java:31)
    at edu.co.ucatolica.trabajaya.service.ContratoServiceImpl.save(ContratoServiceImpl.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:338)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy138.save(Unknown Source)
    at edu.co.ucatolica.trabajaya.controller.ContratoController.crearContratoPost(ContratoController.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:871)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:881)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: What is the relationship between Contrato and Trabajo entities ? Also, is there any cascade configuration between them ?

Comment: @SB Yes, the problem I had was that between them their relationship was one to many, and I had CascadeType.ALL. Even so, I removed that cascade between them but now I have another error: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found shared references to a collection: package.Usuario.contratoCollection

Comment: Full stacktrace or atleast until the service invocation point might help. Looks like Contrato has a Usuario and Usuario further has a Contrato collection.

Comment: Fix it and enter the data correctly. I will publish the solution in case someone later encounters this error. Thank you